# Free Partition Migration Tool

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, software-rec, clone, migration

I'm looking for a free tool that will move a single partition from one drive to another.  I have found tools like [HDClone](http://hdclone-free-edition.en.softonic.com/) and [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org/) but both want to clone the entire hard drive, not just one partition.  Is there such a tool that doesn't cost money?

Answer (score 3):

You could try [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

It has a [nice GUI](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php) and you can cut and paste partitions from one drive to another.

The easiest way to use it probably to boot from the [GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php).

Comment: I found GPArted hard to do an entire disk at once, and in fact went to CloneZilla to do the entire disk at once, successully.

Comment: @geoffc - The question is asking for the opposite - it's asking how to do a single partition and *not* the whole disk - so GParted will be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely clone single partitions with CloneZilla. I've done it before and I'll need to do it again fairly soon. What you do is that when it comes to the selection of what to clone, you select that you want to clone a certain partition and not a whole drive. Problem sorted..

Comment: I didn't like CloneZilla - very confusing. Whilst Symantec Ghost isn't free, I've never had any trouble with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/features.asp).  It doesn't appear to be able to move partitions, but you could create an image of the partition and then restore it to the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

[Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/download/trueimage/) has a free 15 day trial and enables you to do it.

Comment: I'm trying Acronis True Image Home 2010 and I definitely do not see this ability in it.  I am only able to clone a whole hard drive.

Comment: I click on "Backup and Restore," then "Backup," then "Next." Select "My Computer" and click "Next." Select "Disks and partitions" and click "Next." From here you should be able to select an individual partition to backup. I've been using True Image 11 so maybe this option is gone from the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, dd would be the tool for you....just be careful with the -if= and -of= flags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is  [Acronis® Migrate Easy 7.0](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/migrateeasy/)